# Azure Data Factory remove characters in every row of CSV file

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have CSV file with 4 columns and the name of the headers is similar into my MS SQL table. But whenever I ran the Copy Data activity it gives me this error message.

```
Operation on target Insert Into Temp Boston Table failed: ErrorCode=DelimitedTextMoreColumnsThanDefined,
'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Error found when processing
'Csv/Tsv Format Text' source 'MDailyValues.csv' with row number 4: found more columns than expected column count 4.
,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common
```

When I open the CSV file using Excel App it seems normal, there are no extra columns added but when I open the file using Notepad++ it's different.

You can see there are two **extra commas (,,)** at the last part every row.

If the row only contains data from the first and second column that's not an issue but if the row has all the 4 columns that where the issue is.

For example in this case, the data with name Samantha will throw an error in ADF.

```
Name,Country,Age,Gender
Erick,,
Paula,Germany,,
Samantha,France,20,Female,,
```

I'm sure this is where the issue is, because whenever I delete the last 2 commas in the last row,it works fine even though there's still last 2 commas in other rows.

**Is there a way to remove those last 2 commas in every row? In dataflow or any other workaround?**

Based on @Aswin's answer here's the flow I've created.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Now here's where the issue is. I can't create an expression in the derived column.**

[image]
[image]

Here's the error message.

[image]

Comment: Even the lineitem with Name=Erick may cause issue. It has only 2 commas.

Comment: Can you share the exact requirement with correct sample data?

Comment: After several testing the Name = Erick with 2 commas doesn't give issues. Only for data that completes the whole column that causes this error. As for the sample data all that I can share is I'm doing this for 8K records and with 189 columns in the csv file

Answer (score 0):

You can use ADF data flow to remove the extra commas which are present at the end of the data. Below are the detailed steps to do this.

- **Step:1** Take the source transformation in the  dataflow and add the source delimited file as dataset. In dataset settings, **do not** give `comma(,)` as delimiter. (Here, I have given `|` as delimiter)

[image]

All data will be displayed in single column.

- **Step:2** Take the derived column and give the expression as `substringIndex({Name,Country,Age,Gender},',',4)`. This will take the substring of the column till 4th comma in the input string.

[image]

- **Step:3** Take the Parse transformation. Give Format as **Delimited Text**. Then select comma as column delimiter. Give the Column and expression name as same as input column name. In output column type, give the value as `(Name as string, Country as string, Age as integer,Gender as string)`

[image]

Data preview of Parse transformation:
[image]

- **Step:4** Take the derived column transformation and extract the data for columns `Name`, `Age`, `Country`, `Gender` from Json column.
  [image]
- **Step:5** Then take the select transformation and take only 4 columns and deselect the Json column.
  [image]
- **Step:6** Take the sink transformation and Azure sql database table as sink dataset.
  Take this dataflow in the pipeline and execute the pipeline.

You can also stage the result of step:2 data in blob storage and then try to copy the staged data to SQL database.

Comment: Hi Aswin, on step 2. What should I put in the Columns properties? As you've mentioned I need to put that Expression but on the Column I don't see anything from the dropdown selection.

Comment: I gave the same column name. [Screenshot of step2](https://i.imgur.com/UgknTME.png). This will replace the existing values with the result of expression. You can create new column also by giving some different name.

Comment: It's giving me "Type Mismatch: Column Not Found" in step 2. Maybe there's a limit on how long the character must be in a column. It's a 189 column.
I've checked the data set and it's reading properly also checked data preview of the Data Flow in Step 1. It's grabbing the name of the column properly in the Data preview since I've exported it to CSV. The column declared in Step 1 even though it's reading properly still not recognized. 
The only setting I've changed is the Column delimiter in my Source Data set into "|" Pipe. Nothing more or less.

Comment: You can give new column name, with less characters.

Comment: Yes. I did it also. The error is in the expression itself. Not in the column name. Can't paste the whole expression because it exceeds the limit of characters here but here's a sample. 


substringIndex({Eff Date,Agency,Ins Name,Pol Num,ProdID,Pol Date,Prem Paid,Prem ITD,Fund Accum Value,Enh C V Crd...........}, ',', 189)

Comment: Understood! Dont add first row as header , in source dataset

Comment: This will create a default column name for your column and header will be displayed as data.

Comment: My bad. The reason why it doesn't recognized as a column is because I didn't Import the Projection on step 1. Now the issue Im having is on step 4 in expressions. It's giving me "Expression type could not be evaluated .....". And also why I just can't go straight right into the sink after the parse process? It's giving me some issues with JSON forrmatting but I selected Delimited text in step 3.

Comment: If you see the data preview of parse transformation, you can see the all columns will be the subfields of `{Name,Country......}` column. That is the reason , we use step4 and flattening those Json field

Comment: Got it. Makes sense. But still not sure why my expression is not being recognized on step 4. I've tried unchecking the first row header in the source but still this expression doesn't work "AllColumn.{Eff Date}" I have column names with spaces in between even "AllColumn.Agency" doesn't work.

Comment: Are you typing the expression manually? Can you click the expression from the expression values? Check this [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/U810M2K.png)

Comment: Yes I've tried it. I've edited my question with more screenshots to see where I am actually now in Data Flow you created.

Comment: Can you try writing the output of step2 to blob sink? And then use copy activity to copy that data to SQL database?

Comment: It failed. It treats the data as 1 column and enclosed each row in " " that means it's only for 1 column.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255592/discussion-between-aswin-and-zerocool).